# Create zip of folder and then delete the contents

Tags: powershell

I have a simple folder structure that I need to zip up to upload to AWS Lambda function

```
node-modules/
index.js
package.json
```

The files above are in the root directory. Basically the end goal is I would like a zip of all of these files and sub-files/directories instead of the structure as it is.

When I try to run the command below it says it can't access `E://apps/myapp/release.zip` because it's being used by another process. However I can see it starts to create release.zip but it does not have all the contents.

```
Add-Type -Assembly "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem";
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory(E://apps/myapp, E://apps/myapp/release.zip);
```

So I tried another approach. Take the folder and two files and copy them into a temporary folder, then try to zip it back into the root.

```
Copy-Item E://apps/myapp E://apps/myapp/temp -recurse
```

I do see a `temp/` folder but within the temp folder it's like an inception of never ending copies until the file path gets too long.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue could be that you are creating the zip file in the same folder that you are trying to compress. And you basically do the same thing when you tried using the temporary folder, hence the inception.

Try creating destination outside of the source folder being compressed.

```
$source = "E://apps/myapp"
$destination = "E://apps/myapp.release.zip"

# If the archive already exists, an IOException exception is thrown.
if(Test-Path $destination) {
    Remove-Item -Path $destination -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false
}

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" )
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)

# Once archive created delete folder
if(Test-Path $destination) {
    Remove-Item -Path $source -Force -Recurse -Confirm:$false
    Write-Host "directory removed: $source"
}
```

Comment: This certainly works. Part that I didn't mentioned is that I'm doing all of this in octopus deploy. Not sure if it's best practice to do things outside of the installation directory, but I'm giving it a shot!

Comment: Can you add -Force to .net assemblies? I'd like to write that file regardless if it exists or not. Should only exist if there is a failure further down the release path.

Comment: I don't think i totally understand your question in last comment. You could do a check if destination exists before creating zip and delete if it is